# Why isn't Django rendering my block content or recognizing a logged in user?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have `base.html` which contains a `{%block bodycontent %}` and `{% endblock %}` tag, this template works everywhere else so far and resides in the project level templates directory.  Cool.

Then, in an app specific template directory, I have `directory.html` which properly has the `{% extends 'base.html' %}`

However, there's two problems:  If I log in and go to the `/directory/` url my nav-bar (which is in the `base.html` template) doesn't show the user being logged in (navigating away from the page resume normal logged in user display of the nav-bar).

So it looks like the `directory.html` template isn't receiving the user object and the `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` is failing and simply rendering the not logged in version.

The other problem is that `directory.html` doesn't fill the `bodycontent` at all.  Or anything.  I've even inserted standard text and extra HTML tags to try to see something but nothing renders except the `base.html` template

**project level urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', LandingPage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^about/', AboutPage.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^login/', loginPage, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logoutPage, name='logout'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name='admin'),
    url(r'^register/', registrationPage, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/', include(khusers_urlpatterns)),
    url(r'^directory/', displayDirectory, name = 'directory'),
    url(r'^addfriend/', AddFriend, name="add friend")
)
```

**from the views.py**

```
@login_required
def displayDirectory (request, options=None):
    """displays a list of public profile pages"""
    latestModUsers = KHPublicPage.objects.order_by('-lastModified')[:20]
    template = loader.get_template('khusers/directory.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {'profiles': latestModUsers})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

**directory.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block bodycontent %}

{% comment %}
Context expected:
    request.user as user
     a list of khusers.models.KHPublicPage as 'profiles'

        aboutMe
        displayName




bootstrap glyphicons:
    use span class ="badge one of the following"
    glyphicon glyphicon-ok
    glyphicon glyphicon-remove
{% endcomment %}
<div class="container">
    {% for person in profiles %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"> {{person.displayName}} </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h4> {{person.aboutMe}} </h4>
            <br />
            <form action="/addfriend/" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" value ="{{person.pk}}" name="requestee">

                <input type="text" name="note" placeholder="Let's be friends!">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add friend</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
{% load static from staticfiles %}



<!-- pre headcontent django tag -->
{% block headcontent %}

{% endblock %}
<!-- post headcontent django tag -->
<title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}
</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'kh.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">stuff</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="" action="/about/">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="" action="/support/">Other Things</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right btn-danger" style="margin-left: 10px;" href="/logout/">Logout </a>
                <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right btn-info" style="margin-left: 10px;" href="/profile/" > {{user.username}}</a>
            {% else %}
            <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right khtopbarbuttons" style="margin-left: 10px;" href="/register/">Register</a>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right khtopbarbuttons" role="form" action ='/login/' method='post'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control" name="username" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 10px;">Sign in</button>
                </form>

            {% endif %}
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container khcontainerpadded">

                <!-- Pre bodycontent django tag -->
                {% block bodycontent %}
?
                {% endblock %}
                <!-- post bodycontent django tag -->
    </div>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first: use a RequestContext then you'll have the User, because it is set in a middleware :)

Comment: show us the base.html too

Comment: @lalo - perfect, now the navbar retains login, thanks for that :-)

Comment: To clarify still nothing rendering inside the `{% block bodycontent %}` and `{% endblock %}` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be something to do with the way Django 'compiles' and caches templates.

I tried all sorts of things, refreshed everything, yada yada yada.

What eventually fixed it was renaming directory.html to directory2.html in both the filesystem and adjusting the view code to load the new file.

Bam, instantly working.

Renamed it back, still working.

I had cleared my browser cache, so I think it's some of the inner black magic of Django acting up.

Oh well live and learn or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had closed by script tag as

`#<Script href... />`
Instead of:
`#<Script href... ></Script>`

So the tag never closed and the rest of the page became a part of the script tag

I used hash as i don't know how to answer here... The script tag was not showing in my posted answer